# Seed of Random Value can't be as input never?

Tags: geometry-nodes, random

[image]

I connected the seed of Random Value to Random_seed of Repeat zone as driver or data path, but the output of repeat zone is as same as before, 0.

I just want to change that seed not using other stuff like Noise Texture as I repeat, but could it work?